# Wait... what was I going to say again?

Tags: code-golf, string

I often forget what I wanted to say when the teacher calls on me to speak. Can you make me a tool to solve this?

Requirements:

- The program must loop as follows:

  - First, take in input
  - If the input is empty, print the last stored question.
  - Otherwise, store the input as a question.

Notes:

- The input will never be empty if there are no questions stored.

Clarification: **The program does not need to store multiple questions.** <sup><sub>I originally wanted it to store multiple, but I changed it after many people misunderstood the question.</sub></sup>

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the smallest number of bytes wins.

Comment: Did you mean "previously stored question"? I find "last stored question" confusing as it suggests you might store more than one question.

Comment: @Neil It's supposed to be storing more than one question, but since many answers already misunderstood the question, I'll just leave it be.

Answer (score 10):

## Perl, <s>13</s> <s>17</s> 14 +1 = 15 bytes

```
/./?$;=$_:say$
```

+1 for the `-n` flag
(saved 4 bytes thanks to @Dada)

As long as the input is not equal to the carriage return, it stores the input in `$;`.  If it is equal to the carriage return, it prints what's already in `$;`.

This assumes that all input can be characterized as questions, even if grammatically, they are not such.

Comment: You probably wanted to write `ne` instead of `eq` (right now this doesn't work).

Comment: You can save three byte by doing `/./` instead of `$/ne$_` ;-)

Answer (score 8):

## 05AB1E, <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

Thanks @daHugLenny and @Adnan for 1 byte!
Thanks @Emigna for 1 byte!

```
[IDõQiX,ëU
```

Comment: I can't test now, but I think you can remove the last character.

Comment: Yes, you can remove the last bracket (it will be auto-completed).

Comment: If you replace `®` and `©` with `X` and `U`, you don't need the backslash.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 49 bytes

```
g s=getLine>>=(#s)
""#s=putStr s>>g s
l#s=g l
g""
```

How it works: start  with `g ""`. The parameter `s` of function `g` is the question in store. `g` reads the next line from stdin and passes it (and also s) to `#`. If the line is empty, `#` prints the store and calls `g` again. If the line is not empty, `g` is called with the line as the new store.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <del>36</del> <del>34</del> 31 bytes

```js
for(;;b?a=b:alert(a))b=prompt()
```

An infinite loop keeps asking for input and stores it in `b`. It the input is not empty it's then stored in `a`, otherwise the value of `a` is printed.

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions

Comment: Nice answer. You can save a byte by removing the `1`, and another by moving `b?a=b:alert(a)` into the last section within the for-loop (i.e. `for(a=0;;b?a=b:alert(a))b=prompt()`)

Comment: In fact `a=0` is not necessary neither. Since the input can only be empty if there are questions stored, `a` won't be referenced if it hasn't been assigned.

Comment: also stops the browser for a few seconds with firefox-49.0.2

Comment: @Oliver So what, the effect is the same. I could say old values remain stored in memory, just not referenced.

Comment: No, you need to be able to store multiple at once.

Comment: The only requirement in your question is that empty input prints the last stored question. Why do you want me to hold references to previously stored questions?

Comment: @bunyaCloven For me it only stops the browser when I tell it to block dialogs. That's expected due to the infinite loop. After some seconds the browser detects the problem and kills the JS.

Comment: yes but i couldn't manage to get out anyway

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 44 bytes

```
If[(b=InputString[])=="",Print@a,a=b]~Do~∞
```

Full program. The Unicode character is U+221E INFINITY for `\[Infinity]`.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, 31 bytes

```
while 1: I=input()or I;print(I)
```

[Try it out!](http://ideone.com/6B90xU)

-1 byte thanks to Flp.Tkc

Comment: you can write that while loop on 1 line

Answer (score 1):

## reticular, 12 bytes

```
id""E[$dp]~*
```

[Try it online!](http://reticular.tryitonline.net/#code=aWQiIkVbJGRwXX4q&input=SGVsbG8_CldoZXJlIGFtIEk_CmlkawoKb2gsIHRoYW5rcwp3ZWxsLCBzbyB0aGVyZSdzIHRoYXQKaHVoPyB3aGF0J3MgcmV0aWN1bGFyPwoKb2gsIHRoYXQncyBteSBxdWVzdGlvbi4gY29vbC4KCi4uLiE)

### Explanation

```
id""E[$dp]~*
i             take a line of input     [input]
 d""E         push equality with ""    [input, input == ""]
     [$dp]    push that func           [input, input == "", [$p]]
         ~*   execute it iff equal
              on equal:
      $       drop empty input
       dp     duplicate then print the TOS
              this wraps around to the beginning, taking another line of input
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python3 - 49 bytes

```
s=""
while 1:
 b=input()
 if b:s=b
 else:print(s)
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'b' is not defined`

Comment: @shooqie Ah, I typed this with my phone so I accidentally left out `b=input()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 6 bytes

```
z=z~zr
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=z%3Dz%7Ezr&input=%3F%3F%3F%0A%0A%0Ahi%0Awhat%3F%0A%0A%3F)

```
     r - while 1:
z      -   input() or z.contents
 =z    -  z.contents = ^
   ~z  -  z.contents
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 34 bytes

```
s=""
while[print(s)]:s=input()or s
```

Comment: It doesn't? It works fine for me

Comment: The spec doesn't ask to store multiple questions?

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 60 bytes

```py
q=[]
while 1:
 s=input()
 if''<s:q+=[s]
 else:print(q.pop())
```

Answer (score 0):

## CMD, 37 bytes

Sadly `set` does not take empty input:(

```
set/p a=
if %a%.=. echo b
set b=%a%
c
```

in a file names `c.cmd` or

```
set/p a=
if %a%.=. echo b
set b=%a%
%0
```

in any file. Working(Use `-` as empty):

```
set/p a=
if %a%.=-. echo b
set b=%a%
c
```

Comment: `set/p` will never make a variable empty, so at the very least you need `set a=` on the first line; also I think you mean `set b=%a%`.

Answer (score 0):

## C, <s>73</s> 63 bytes

```c
g(){char a[99],x;for(;;){gets(a);if(*a)x=*a;else*a=x,puts(a);}}
```

Only uses 1 buffer and a single char for handling the logic. If user inputs nothing, only the first char in the buffer gets overwritten by `'\0'`, in that case it gets restored from `x` and printed, otherwise copy the first letter into `x` for later use.

Previous code:

```c
main(){char a[99],b[99];for(;;){gets(a);if(*a)strcpy(b,a);else puts(b);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## APLX, 19 bytes

```
a←⍞⋄→(0=⍴a)/1⋄a⋄→1
```

#### Explanation:

```
⍝ Note: the ⋄ symbols are statement separators, so I've replaced them here with newlines

a←⍞           ⍝ get an input string (⍞) and store it in variable a
→(0=⍴a)/1     ⍝ if the length of a (⍴a) is 0, goto (→) the start of this program (1)
a             ⍝ else, print a
→1            ⍝ goto the start of the program (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, <s>189</s> <s>187</s> 178 bytes..

```
class M{public static void main(String[]a){String s="",x;do{x=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();if(x.isEmpty())Syste‌​m.out.println(s);els‌​e s=x;}while(1>0);}}
```

-9 bytes by using `new java.util.Scanner` directly, thanks to *@cliffroot*.

Probably the first time I used a `do-while` in a codegolf challenge..

When functions are allowed instead of programs, it's **135 bytes** (still many times more than most other answers..)

Comment: this is a a bit shorter and seems to be working – `void c(){for(String s="",x;(x=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine())!=null;)if(x.isEmpty())System.out.println(s);else s=x;}`

Comment: @cliffroot Ummm.. aren't you missing a `for` or `while` somewhere?.. What is `(x=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine())!=null;)`?

Comment: Yeah, I managed to miss for before that somehow :)
it was supposed to be `void c(){for(String s="",x;for(x=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine())!=null;)if(x.isEmpty())System.out.println(s);else s=x;}` and it's actually 1 byte longer then the version with `do-while` is – `void c(){String s="",x;do{x=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();if(x.isEmpty())System.out.println(s);else s=x;}while(1>0);}`

Comment: @cliffroot Ah of course.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## sed, 10 bytes

```
/./{x;d};g
```

Explanation:

```
      (implicit at start of program) read input, overwriting old input
/./{  If the input is nonempty
  x;  swap the input with the hold space
  d   then restart, without any implicit printing of input
};    end if statement
g     Append the hold space to the [empty] input
      (implicit at end of program) print the input, then restart
```

Nice to see an exoteric (i.e. "not esoteric") language tying with some of the golfing languages!